# Azure media player playback issue in IE and firefox

Tags: azure, media-player, azure-media-services

Getting an error while playing videos from azure media services. For the last 2 weeks  i am facing this issue.

> In IE, no compatible source found for the current browser environment
>   (0x10600003),

In firefox,The video playback was aborted due to a corruption problem or because the video used features your browser did not support.

Comment: Are u tryied from different machines? In my experience, when AMP stop working in a machine the only know way (for me) is reinstall the computer OS.

Comment: I tried in different machines. It is not playing. even azure media player site itself throwing the same error. http://amsplayer.azurewebsites.net

Comment: A few questions: 
1. What OS are you using?
2. What versions of each browser are you using?  
3. Do you have Flash and/or Silverlight installed for and enabled in each browser?

Answer (score 0):

- 0x10600000 - HTML5 playback issue, or [unsupported DRM](http://www.drmtoday.com/platforms/) selected by JS.
- 0x10600001 - Flash player issue.
- 0x10600002 - Silverlight player issue.
- 0x10600003 - Autoselect failed to find a player.

From the gear menu in IE11, select *Manage add-ons* and ensure [Microsoft
   Silverlight](http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/) is installed and *Enabled*.