# Azure Media Player playback failure: no compatible source found for the current browser environment (0x10600003)

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I'm developing a Video on Demand feature for a Django project of mine. It's going to be powered by Azure Media Services.

Currently, I'm trying to run an uploaded video via the following code:

```
<video id="azuremediaplayer" class="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin amp-big-play-centered" controls autoplay width="640" height="400" poster="" data-setup='{"techOrder": ["azureHtml5JS", "flashSS", "silverlightSS", "html5"], "nativeControlsForTouch": false}'>
    <source src="{{ video.streaming_url }}" type="video/mp4" />
    <p class="amp-no-js">
        To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that supports HTML5 video
    </p>
    </video>
```

where `{{ video.streaming_url }}` contains a streaming url of the sort `http://example.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/66193aae-b739-4cb5-b4b9-f4a4a151c791/myproject.ism/manifest`.

My problem is that I get the error **no compatible source found for the current browser environment (0x10600003)**. In fact, I get that error when I go to http://ampdemo.azureedge.net/azuremediaplayer.html as well (i.e. an official azure media player demo).

It seems the `0x10600003` error code implies `Autoselect failed to find a player`. *Note that Youtube videos work perfectly in my environment*. My OS is Ubuntu 14.04, and the browser is Mozilla Firefoz 41.0.1. A previous [unaccepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33820913/azure-media-player-playback-issue-in-ie-and-firefox) guided the op to install and enable Silverlight. I can't expect all my users to do that. How do I get playback to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure Media Player is built on 4 different players, a DASH player, a Flash player, the Silverlight player, and the native implemented player for the browser you're watching the video on. These different "Player Techs" playback different protocols supported my Azure Media Services- DASH, Smooth, and HLS.

AMP intelligently decides which player/playback protocol to use for a specific/device or browser by looking at what technologies/features the browser supports. First, it'll check if the browser supports [Media Source Extensions](https://w3c.github.io/media-source/). MSE allows the browser to playback adaptive bitrate streams without the use of plugins like Flash and Silverlight, it's supported in most modern browsers, but not always in older versions of those browsers. If MSE is supported,AMP will playback your content using the MPEG-Dash protocol and you're good to go. If MSE isn't supported, AMP will check and see if Flash is installed and then if Silverlight is installed. If either of these are true it will play back using the installed plugin and the Smooth Streaming protocol. If neither of them are installed, it will try to play back via the native html5 video tag implementation of the browser. This is completely dependent on the browser, and most do not support ABR streams natively (except, for example, Safari via HLS)

**Your short answer**, given this background information, is that because you are using an older version of FF that does NOT support MSE, you need to install either Flash or Silverlight to play back your adaptive bitrate streams.

a few mitigations for you/customers:
1) install Flash/Silverlight
2) download an up-to-date version of FF, we recommend this for sure because MSE is supported in v42 but in v47+ Google Widevine protected content is supported, which means you can playback DRM encrypted content without Silverlight

see Azure Media Player's [Compatibility Matrix](http://aka.ms/ampdocs#compatibility-matrix) for more info on what's supported on which browsers. 
If you have any more questions, you can email me at ampinfo@microsoft.com, hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I've actually changed my approach a bit, but I still need guidance from you folks, so I'll drop you an email.

Answer (score -1):

I just knocked off the content policy and created a new one and it started working again.